# Run composer command sequence in a batch file

Tags: php, batch-file, xampp, composer-php

I would like to sequence some composer commands in a batch file. After the first command the cmd window exists. The second line is not triggered.

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel %project% 5.4.*
composer require "laravelcollective/html"
```

Is it possible to suppress the exit?

Comment: `start "" composer ....`

Comment: Start will open a new command window. It triggers the second command right after the first. The first command should finish first.

I could submit a /wait, but then it will only continue if I close the command window (manually).

Comment: check if `composer` is a bat file. Try with `call composer ....`

Comment: Call did the trick. Thank you